# Computing with number of stack items

Tags: formal-languages, programming-languages, computation-models, stacks

For [stack-oriented programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language), how many top-most items of the stack are needed to be accessible in order to be Turing complete?

Is it enough to be able to access just the top-most item? Two items? Three? Any item?

In the case of [Forth](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Forth_stack_operators), is it necessary to have `rot`, `pick`, `roll`? Why does `rot` operates with exactly top three items?

Comment: What can the "items" be? ​ If they're bounded-size, then restricting to a bounded number of items just gives you [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton)s, else see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I would say bounded-size, otherwise couldn't I somehow encode the rest of the stack in just one item?

Comment: @D.W. Just a guess: isn't it possible to simulate [two-counter machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine#Two-counter_machines_are_Turing_equivalent_.28with_a_caveat.29) if I have `rot`, i.e. access to at least three top-most items?

Comment: @D.W. obviously, Forth has some constructs which allow it to be more powerful than a stack machine, including a second stack (the "return" stack) and random access memory. But I think your answer for a hypothetical Forth with a single stack is correct, and should be turned into an answer.

Comment: @EcirHana, how would you simulate a two-counter machine using rot, if the items on the stack are of fixed size?  (the counter in a two-counter machine can have arbitrarily large values)

Comment: @D.W. I don't really know. I might very well mix up a few things I read recently... Isn't it enough that the stack is unbounded, i.e. that it can hold infinite number of (bounded-sized) items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what kinds of things you can store on the stack.

If each item on the stack is of unbounded size, you can simulate a [two-counter machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine), which is [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine#Two-counter_machines_are_Turing_equivalent_.28with_a_caveat.29).  Therefore, in this case, you can achieve Turing-completeness with just the ability to access the top two items on the stack.

If items are bounded-size, restricting to access a bounded number of top-most items of the stack gives something equivalent in power to a PDA.  (For instance, suppose all you can do is access the top 5 items of the stack, and use that together with a finite control to transition to a new state of the finite control and either push/pop.  Then grouping the items into 5-tuples, we can build an equivalent machine where you only need to access the topmost item.  That machine is a PDA.)  Therefore, in this case, it's not Turing complete with access to any finite number of items at the top of the stack.